# Integration with right rectangle rule

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to complete the task of integrating with the right rectangle rule, but I am stuck at one moment. The first two values are being outputted, but further ones are just 0...
The task is about starting with iteration count 3 and continuing up to 512, by multiplying iteration count by 2 every time.
I feel something is wrong here, but I can't see what. Let the test values be, as in the task: lower: -3, upper: 6, starting iteration count: 3

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double Function(double x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return (1 / sqrt(25 + (3 * x)));
    else
        return pow(x, 2) + 0.2;
}

double Integrate(int upper, int lower, int iteration_count)
{
    double pre_sum = (double)((double)(upper - lower) / iteration_count);
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1, step ; i < iteration_count; i++)
    {
        sum += Function(lower + pre_sum + i);
    }

    return sum * pre_sum;
}

int main()
{
    int upper, lower, iteration_count;
    cout << "Enter lower bound: ";
    cin >> lower;
    cout << "Enter upper bound: ";
    cin >> upper;
    cout << "Enter iteration count: ";
    cin >> iteration_count;

    for (int i = iteration_count; i < iteration_count * 512; i=i*2)
    {
        cout << "Integration result: " << Integrate(upper, lower, i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But values keep increasing drastically:

```
Enter lower bound: -3
Enter upper bound: 6
Enter iteration count: 3
Integration result: 16.2
Integration result: 33.0094
Integration result: 198.962
Integration result: 1138.16
Integration result: 5578.55
Integration result: 24809.2
Integration result: 104733
Integration result: 430463
Integration result: 1.74547e+06
```

Comment: You were supposed to call `Function(lower + pre_sum *i)`

Comment: Did you just repost the same exact question after the first one was closed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242605/right-rectangle-rule-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `sum += Function(lower + pre_sum + i);` to `sum += Function(lower + pre_sum * i);`. That is, you should multiply by `i` rather than add it. `i` represents the index of the iteration (indexed by 1 for right-rectangle integration; indexed by 0 for left-rectangle integration.)
2. Change `for (int i = 1, step ; i < iteration_count; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= iteration_count; i++)`. That is, check for less-than-or-equal rather than less-than inequality. Otherwise, the number of iterations performed is actually one less than `iteration_count`, which is likely unintended behavior. `step` was also removed, since it's dead code.

Output:

```
Enter lower bound: -3
Enter upper bound: 6
Enter iteration count: 3
Integration result: 136.8
Integration result: 103.081
Integration result: 87.911
Integration result: 80.7481
Integration result: 77.2722
Integration result: 75.5606
Integration result: 74.7114
Integration result: 74.2885
Integration result: 74.0774
```